# Mongotemplate custom converter not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mapping, mongotemplate

I have a list of documents called customers that I retrieved using mongotemplate, bellow some of the documents:

```
    {"customer": {"entityPerimeter": "abp", "name": "ZERZER", "siren": "6154645", "enterpriseId": "546456", "ic01": "", "marketingOffer": "qlksdjf", "irType": "Router", "offerSpecificationOfferLabel": "2Mb"}}
    {"customer": {"entityPerimeter": "sdf", "name": "qazer", "siren": "156", "enterpriseId": "546456", "ic01": "", "marketingOffer": "qlksdjddddsqf", "irType": "Ruter", "offerSpecificationOfferLabel": "2Mb"}}
    {"customer": {"entityPerimeter": "zer", "name": "fazdsdfsdgg", "siren": "sdfs", "enterpriseId": "1111", "ic01": "", "marketingOffer": "qsdfqsd", "irType": "Router", "offerSpecificationOfferLabel": "2Mb"}}
```

That what I did in mongodb to have this result:

```
public List<DBObject> findAllCustomersByExtractionDateMongo(LocalDate extractionDate) {
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where(EXTRACTION_DATE).is(extractionDate)),
                project(CUSTOMER).andExclude("_id"),
                group().addToSet("$customer").as("distinct_customers"),
                unwind("distinct_customers"),
                project().andExclude("_id").and("distinct_customers").as("customer"),
                project().andExclude("distinct_customers")

        );
        
        return template
                .aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION, DBObject.class)
                .getMappedResults();
    }
```

Now what I really want is to map those Documents to a Class called Customer:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Customer {
    private String entityPerimeter;
    private String name;
    private String siren;
    private String enterpriseId;
    private String ic01;
    private String marketingOffer;
    private String product;
    private String irType;
}
```

I tried to do that by creating a DTO interface:

```
public interface DocumentToCustomerMapper {
    String NULL = "null";
    
    static Customer getFilter(DBObject document) {
        var customer = new Customer();
        customer.setSiren(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.SIREN.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setEnterpriseId(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.ENTERPRISE_ID.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setEntityPerimeter(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.ENTITY_PERIMETER.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setName(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.NAME.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setIc01(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.IC_01.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setMarketingOffer(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.MARKETING_OFFER.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setProduct(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.PRODUCT.value())).orElse(NULL));
        customer.setIrType(Optional.ofNullable((String) document.get(CustomerAttributes.IR_TYPE.value())).orElse(NULL));
        return customer;
    }
}
```

Then in the `findAllCystomersByExtractionDateMongo()` I'm doing this:

```
public List<Customer> findAllCustomersByExtractionDateMongo(LocalDate extractionDate) {
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where(EXTRACTION_DATE).is(extractionDate)),
            project(CUSTOMER).andExclude("_id"),
            group().addToSet("$customer").as("distinct_customers"),
            unwind("distinct_customers"),
            project().andExclude("_id").and("distinct_customers").as("customer"),
            project().andExclude("distinct_customers")

    );

    final Converter<DBObject, Customer> converter = DocumentToCustomerMapper::getFilter;
    MongoCustomConversions cc = new MongoCustomConversions(List.of(converter));
    ((MappingMongoConverter) template.getConverter()).setCustomConversions(cc);


    return template
            .aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION, Customer.class)
            .getMappedResults();
}
```

But unfortunately it's giving me an exception:

`Couldn't resolve type arguments for class com.obs.dqsc.api.repository.mongo_template.CustomerRepositoryImpl$$Lambda$1333/0x00000008012869a8!`

I tried to remove this code:

```
 final Converter<DBObject, Customer> converter = DocumentToCustomerMapper::getFilter;
 MongoCustomConversions cc = new MongoCustomConversions(List.of(converter));
 ((MappingMongoConverter) template.getConverter()).setCustomConversions(cc);
```

Then all what I'm getting is some null values in my customer objects:

```
Customer(entityPerimeter=null, name=null, siren=null, enterpriseId=null, ic01=null, marketingOffer=null, product=null, irType=null)
Customer(entityPerimeter=null, name=null, siren=null, enterpriseId=null, ic01=null, marketingOffer=null, product=null, irType=null)
Customer(entityPerimeter=null, name=null, siren=null, enterpriseId=null, ic01=null, marketingOffer=null, product=null, irType=null)
```

*Note: for performance issues, I don't want to do any mapping in the java side, also I don't want to use a global converter in my mongo configuration.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a method reference to express your converter:

```
    final Converter<DBObject, Customer> converter = DocumentToCustomerMapper::getFilter;
```

(Expanding the method reference to a lambda won't work either.)

Try rewriting that snippet to something else (such as an anonymous inner class).

Here is a very similar issue reported, including info on how to work around this problem: https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/120